# Using Scala Option list or array in MySQL prepareStatement

Tags: mysql, scala, jdbc, spray

I am developing a REST web API using Spray, Scala and MySQL. User has to pass an array parameter (along with others) in the POST request. This is an optional parameter. I have successfully written Scala functions to take these parameters, query MySQL database and present appropriate output in JSON to the user.

However I am stuck with this array parameter. I have some problem converting the Scala `Option[Array[String]]` (or list) into `java.sql.array`.

Here is the sample code:

```
def xyz(a:Option[Array[String]], b:Option[Long]) {
        ------------
        ------------
          if (a == None && b == None) {
    val statement = conn.prepareStatement("select * from table")                                          
    var rs = statement.executeQuery()
    while (rs.next) {
      -------
    }
  }
  else if (a != None && b == None) {
    val statement = conn.prepareStatement("select * from MasterInventory 
                    where ID = (?)")    
      var arr = conn.createArrayof("varchar",a)
      statement.setArray(1,arr)
      ------------
      ------------
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

createArrayof expects a Java array, not the Scala Array you currently have.  To convert it, you can just call `toArray`.
And since you know `a` is not empty, you can directly call `get` to obtain your scala array

```
var arr = conn.createArrayof("varchar", a.get.toArray)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Karl. But this helps.Thanks a lot.